# Traefik allowing users to their domain names to my service

Tags: ssl, amazon-route53, traefik

I am using Traefik as a reverse proxy and AWS Route 53 Hosted zone for my DNS. I want to allow users to connect their domain or subdomain to my service.
I have read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73126594/allowing-users-to-point-their-domain-names-to-my-service) with a lot of attention:

But I am still facing issue with the SSL, indeed here is the error I get: `ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT`

The idea would be to let the user point their domain to my service. And here is my traefik configuration of the service:

```yaml
version: '3.9'

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true

services:
  my_php_apache:
    build: docker/php
    container_name: mywebapp
    volumes:
      - ./docker/php/vhosts:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled:ro,cached
      - ./:/var/www/webapplication:cached
    networks:
      - proxy
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mywebapp.rule=HostRegexp(`{subdomain:[a-z0-9-]+}.mywebapp.com`) || Host(`mywebapp.com`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mywebapp.tls=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mywebapp.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mywebapp.tls.certresolver=mydnschallenge"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mywebapp.tls.domains[0].main=mywebapp.com"
      - "traefik.http.routers.mywebapp.tls.domains[0].sans=*.mywebapp.com"
```

I have tried by creating a CNAME from `subdomain.external.com` to `test.mywebapp.com`, and i get the error above.

I have tried to add the following in the `docker-compose.yaml` but without success.

```
- "traefik.http.routers.mywebapp.rule=HostRegexp(`{subdomain:[a-z0-9-]+}.mywebapp.com`) || Host(`mywebapp.com`) || Host(`subdomain.external.com`)"
```

For your information, the SSL certificates are well generated by Traefik for `mywebapp.com` and `*.webapp.com`. And `subdomain.external.com`, for my test has a valid ssl certificate as well.

Comment: If "subdomain.external.com, for my test has a valid ssl certificate as well." then you should not get "ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT" when trying to reach subdomain.external.com , so start your investigation from there.